# Send data to google analytics using trackEvent method

Tags: html, google-analytics, onclick

I tried to send data to google analytics but I have a problem. Code below does not work:

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Bid', 'Bid',{{ (data.article_id) }},{{ data.id }}])"
```

while following code works:

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Bid', 'Bid', 'Test', 4])"
```

I do not get the errors. can you help me please? Thx in advance

Comment: Minor english update. Make the two chunks more visible.

Comment: What are the things in the curly braces supposed to represent? Is that correct JS syntax? Are they supposed to evaluate to something? Need more info.